# Open binary data in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I want to read from a binary data file,
in the old matlab version of my script this is done by

```
file=fread(data,'bit16');
```

which would be the equivalent thing in python ?
i tried

```
with open file(data, "rb") as f:
    d = np.fromfile(f, "<i2", count = 10000)
```

since [the matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) says that bitn is of the type signed integer with n bits

i tried different dtypes `( "<>i2", "int16")` unfortunately this doesnt give me the rigth data.

Comment: how did you write the `data` file?

Comment: Just for whatever it's worth, `np.fromfile('test.dat', np.int16)` properly recovers data written from matlab with `fwrite(fid, data, 'bit16')` on my system.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `float16` data type associated with `numpy.frombuffer` that deals with the [half precision floting point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) (`bit16` in matlab). The type doc is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).